# Path SQLSERVER:\7za.exe does not exist?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code in a powershell script. And I have file `7za.exe` in the same directory of the script.

```
param($sql)
$temp = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance sqlserver1 $sql | ConvertTo-Csv > $temp
.\7za.exe a '$temp.zip' '$temp'
```

However, it got the following error. What's the right approach to execute an executable in the same folder right after `invoke-sqlcmd`?

```
SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Path SQLSERVER:\7za.exe does not exist. Please specify a valid path.
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], GenericProviderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GenericProviderException
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the path in the error message, it is "SQLSERVER:\7za.exe" -- so the current working directory for the instance of PowerShell running this script (which you can get using the automatic variable $pwd) is SQLSERVER:\, which is the PSDrive created by the SQL module\snap-in that must be loaded to run the Invoke-SqlCmd cmdlet.

PowerShell scripts do NOT use their current location as the current working directory by default. In PowerShell version 3 and later, however, you can get the script's directory using the automatic variable $PSScriptRoot. In earlier versions, you can generate $PSScriptRoot yourself with:

```
$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

Then you could use this variable in your script like so:

```
& (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot '7za.exe') "$temp.zip" "$temp"
```

Note that I used double quotes around the $temp variable, so that PowerShell would automatically expand the variable into the correct name.

Answer (score 1):

@jbsmith is right about what path to use.  Contributing to this issue is that the SQLPS module changes the current directory to SQLSERVER: when it is imported.